# Using Logarithms

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

\begin{align*}
-2^{n-1} \ln2 &= -100 \ln 10\\
&\\
-100 \ln 10 &= -230\\
&\\
\dfrac{-230}{\ln (2)} &= -333\\
&\\
-2^{n-1} &> -333\\
&\\
(n-1) \ln(-2) &> \ln(-333)
\end{align*}

Here is where I am stuck.

I am not sure if this part is correct: $-n-1=8$. Then solving we would get $-9$.

Comment: Is this an equation or an inequality?  And where do 230, 333 come from?

Comment: @vadim123 Just trying to solve this equation to get one answer for n. I know my working is somewhat correct the way it is.

Comment: $-100\ln(10)\ne -230$.  It is *approximately equal*, but not *equal*.

Comment: Also, note that something is not right, because you're taking $\ln(-2)$, which can't be done in the real number system.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. You really need to get your post right before posting or you will wind up making a mess here (people are eager to help you). I edited (cleaned) one of your edits, only to see you edit that to this. Carefully look at your post. Use parentheses when in doubt. When you are absolutely sure you are done editing, say so and someone might be kind enough to make it look nice. Note that you could be kicked out of the math union for a very long time if you ever try to express the log of a negative number again in this context. $\ln(-2)$, and $\ln(-333)$ do not exist in $\mathbb{R}$!

Comment: @J.W.Perry That was the rule I was trying to remember. Thank you. Sorry about the edits. I am still learning LATEX and got mixed up with what I intended to do. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log is an increasing function. So you can take log in both side of an inequality and that is fine. But you can't take log of negative values like $-2$
The mistake is at $$-2^{n-1}=-333.$$ You missed negative sign at $333$. Then if you correct the next steps it's fine. Also when you multiply both sides of an inequality by negative the sign changes.

$$-2^{n-1} ln2 < -100*ln10$$

$$-2^{n-1}<\cfrac{-100*ln10}{ln2}$$

$$2^{n-1}>\cfrac{100*ln10}{ln2}$$

$$n-1 * ln(2) >ln(\cfrac{100*ln10}{ln2}).$$ And this gives $n>\cfrac{ln(\cfrac{100*ln10}{ln2})}{ln2}+1$

Comment: Thank you MLT. I was trying to get this. I needed to remember the rule for $-$ in logs.

Comment: @user99744 You are most welcome :).

Answer (score 0):

-9 is not correct: if you plug it into a calculator, you find that $2^{-2^{n-1}} = 2^{-2^{-10}} = 2^{-\frac{1}{1024}} \approx 0.99932\ldots$, which is not less than $10^{-100}$.

My recommendation would be to solve for an inequality involving $n$ (i.e. $n < $ some number); then the answer that you want (a single integer for which the inequality is satisfied) could be any integer less than or equal to $n$.

A hint: Your first step is a good start, just be sure to include the less-than sign. So

$$2^{-2^{n-1}} < 10^{-100}$$

becomes

$$-2^{n-1} \ln 2 < -100 \ln 10.$$

Also, recall that when you divide or multiply an inequality by a negative number, you need to switch less than and greater than signs around.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that we take into account negative numbers:
$$-(2^{n-1})\ln(2)<-100\ln(10)$$
$$(2^{n-1})\ln(2)>100\ln(10)$$
^^ note switch in inequality because of multiplying by a negative number...
$$(2^{n-1})<\frac{100\ln(10)}{\ln(2)}$$
^^ Same thing: $\ln(2)<0$.

$$(2^{n-1})<\frac{100\ln(10)}{\ln(2)}$$
$$(n-1)\ln(2)<\ln\left(\frac{100\ln(10)}{\ln(2)}\right)$$
$$(n-1)>\frac{\ln\left(\frac{100\ln(10)}{\ln(2)}\right)}{\ln(2)}$$
$$n>\frac{\ln\left(\frac{100\ln(10)}{\ln(2)}\right)}{\ln(2)}+1$$

For an integer $n$, then simply round up.

Comment: Thank you too anorton. You helped and I understood. Thanks.